# How can I determine that the start of week is Monday or Sunday in different culture in C#

Tags: c#, .net

some country use Monday as the first day in a week, some country use Sunday. 
in C#/.Net, the library Globalization can determine current webpage open in different country, but I didn't find any useful method for determine the which country use which day as start of week.

Comment: Eh, `var result = CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;` or alike?

Comment: You want to know the first day of a week of the user that opens the page in his browser? Is it an ASP.NET app? You have the culture already or you need to determine it?

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is: Is your problem getting the FirstDayOfWeek for a certain culture? Or do you have problems determining the culture of the user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this Globalized TimeFormat

```
 var firstDayOfWeek = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`FirstDayOfWewek`-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.firstdayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `DateTimeFormatInfo` of the culture.

```
var info = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
info.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
```

Comment: I don't know the country code, just use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture to get the  Culture

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, you want to get firts day of week from *country code* (e.g. "RU", "FR", "DE" etc.), not from `CultureInfo` (which is evident):

```
  // Russian culture, Russia
  CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");

  var firstDayOfWeek = ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

  // Monday
  Console.Write(firstDayOfWeek);
```

For country code only it's a harder task:

```
  // Just Russia given as ISO 2 letters country code
  String CountryCode = "RU";

  var days = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
    .Where(item => item.LCID != 4096) // Cultures without region
    .Where(item => String.Equals(new RegionInfo(item.LCID).Name, 
                                 CountryCode,
                                 StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .Select(item => item.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();

  if (days.Length <= 0)
    Console.Write("No such regions found, use default (Sunday?)");
  else if (days.Length == 1)
    Console.Write(days[0]); // <- this will return "Monday"
  else
    Console.Write("Too many variants: " + String.Join(", ", days));
```